# Android: Validatng password ,conform password and passing a string value  through Button

Tags: android, validation, button, android-edittext

I have fields like password,conform password and gender in my registration page

password             edit text

conform password     edit text

gender               (button01)/(button02)

for password and conform password i want to validate both fields ,I mean the entries(string value) of both fields should be same. If both are same then I want to pass only password value to the server  not both values and In case of gender when I click button 01, I want to pass the input as male(string) to server and same in case of female also. How can I do this?

Help is always appreciated...!

Comment: have you already tried to do that yourself? What was the problem? Can you paste some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Check Password.

  Here i write one function for compare password and conform password . In that function 
    you need pass both the password and it will return true if both password are same and 
    return false if both are different.

  ```
   public boolean checkPassWordAndConfirmPassword(String password,String confirmPassword) 
   {
       boolean pstatus = false;
       if (confirmPassword != null && password != null) 
       {
         if (password.equals(confirmPassword)) 
         {
              pstatus = true;
         } 
       }
      return pstatus;
  }
  ```
- Gender Button

  As you said that here you are taking two button for gender . One is for male and another is for female . so you when user click on male button you have to take one string variable and assing the "male" value to that string, if user click female then you have to set "female" to that variable and pass to the server.

Comment: Thanks,but  can we add request.addProperty() inside onclick listner in order to send the button value to server ,see I didnt set any text to the button i should consider the button id