# didn,t work checking between password and repeat password in android

Tags: android

```
........................................
 else if (e8.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    e8.setError("Password is required");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    i = 0;

                }

                else if (e9.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    e9.setError("Password is required");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    j = 0;
                }

                else if (!e8.equals(e9.getText()))
                {
                    e9.setError("Both Passwordsxmvbxb are different");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Correct Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    k = 0;
                }
........................................
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Validatng password ,conform password and passing a string value  through Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409118/android-validatng-password-conform-password-and-passing-a-string-value-throug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be String when you are checking any two string. currenty you are doing `e8.equal` where `e8` is your `EditText` so it will check for equal object. It should be

```
if(!e8.getText().toString().equals(e9.getText().toString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
}

        else if (e9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            e9.setError("Password is required");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            j = 0;
        }

        else if (!e8.getText().toString().equals(e9.getText().toString()))
        {
            e9.setError("Both Passwordsxmvbxb are different");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Correct Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            k = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this approach.

```
if(validate()){
    // perform operation
}
```

method declaration:

```
private boolean validate() 
  {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText())) {

        //toast enter password

        return false;

    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtConfirmPassword.getText())) {

        //toast enter confirm password

        return false;
    } else if (!edtPassword.getText().toString().equals(edtConfirmPassword.getText().toString())) {
        //toast password not match

        return false;
    }
    return true; // considering all conditions are true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.equals` instead of **==** to compare string .